# A trigger that, when deleted from the table, the Client deletes all records from the subordinate

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need help creating a trigger that, when deleted from the table, the Client deletes all records associated with the client from the subordinate. That's what he wrote.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteKlient  ON  Сustomers INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE Z
    FROM deleted d
    JOIN dbo.Orders Z ON d.CustomersID IN(Z.[CustomersID]);

    DELETE dbo.Customers
    FROM deleted
    WHERE deleted.CustomersID=Customers.CustomersID;
END;
```

**Table Customers:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [CustomersID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Customer] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Phone] [dbo].[phone] NULL,
    [organizationid] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [CustomersID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Table Orders:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [OrderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomersID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Numbernaklad] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DateOrders] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Sum] [float] NOT NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Dateotgr] [date] NULL,
    [Prim] [text] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK__Orders__D9B7FE45369C06AC] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ЗаказID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Customer] FOREIGN KEY([CustomersID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomersID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Customers]
GO
```

**Table OrderedGoods:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ordered Goods](
    [OrdersID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WarehouseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Count] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Price] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Sale] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Table Warehouse:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Warehouse](
    [WarehouseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Specific] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Price] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Ostatok] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Adres] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Склад] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

**Table ProductCatalog:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductCatalog](
    [ProductCode] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__КаталогТ__02FE99B3065CA5D4] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

**db schema:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFZC4.png)

Comment: You can declare your FK with `ON DELETE CASCADE` option. No trigger required

Comment: And I need a trigger in my task

Comment: So whats not working about your current trigger? Aside from an incorrect join condition `ON d.КлиентID IN(Z.[КлиентID]);` should be `ON d.КлиентID = Z.[КлиентID];` it looks like it might work?

Comment: here in my table the Order ID is linked to the Ordered goods how do I delete it there

Comment: Yes you can do it with your trigger. Just correct it as @DaleK advices.

Comment: Can I make a nested trigger?

Comment: But the task requires a trigger

Comment: Look, I'm doing a trigger on the Customers table, and I also have a table of Ordered Goods where there is an Order ID that, when the client is deleted, swears that there is an order there.

Comment: It almost works there, I don't understand how to make the Order ID be deleted from the ordered goods so that the client is deleted

Comment: Well, yes, but I don't understand how to do it further

Comment: The bottom line is I delete the client if he has an order, he is deleted, but first the order is checked in the Ordered Goods table if not, the order is deleted if it is there, then it is deleted there later in the order, and then the client himself.

Comment: Okay, let me do it in English right now

Comment: @DaleK I changed

Answer (score 1):

You just need to correct your errors:

1. Your first join condition should be `=` not `IN` as I said in the comments.
2. You need to join your `Customers` table on in the second delete.
3. Add any other dependent child tables in a similar fashion.

Note: For clarity I like my `FROM` to be my table I am deleting from, and I prefer `INNER JOIN` so I don't have to remember that `JOIN` means inner.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteKlient
ON dbo.Сustomers
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE OG
    FROM dbo.OrderedGoods OG
    INNER JOIN dbo.Orders O on O.OrdersId = OG.OrdersId
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.CustomersID = O.CustomersID;

    DELETE O
    FROM dbo.Orders O
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.CustomersID = O.CustomersID;

    DELETE C
    FROM dbo.Customers C
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.CustomersID = C.CustomersID;
END;
```

I demonstrate this working for you with this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jypm1Nzx)